Using NuGetize with a 'package project' to pack both API any analyzer
I have an API and an analyzer project and I want to ship them together. I want to follow the conventions in the structure. And I am trying to use a packaging project with NuGetize. But the result is not quite as I expected. Maybe I am using NuGetize not in a proper way, misunderstood something, or there are limitations.
This is the portion from the .msbuildproj file referencing the individual projects:
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\Integration.Analyzers\Integration.Analyzers.csproj" PackFolder="analyzers" PackSymbols="false" />
   <ProjectReference Include="..\Integration\Integration.csproj" PackFolder="lib" PackSymbols="true"/>
 </ItemGroup>

And the result:

My issues are - although none seems of paramount relevance:

PackSymbols="false" is not honored
the content of lib folder is repeated in the analyzer folder (the analyzer indeed references the integration project that in turn references the helper) - this makes some sense
if I try to use PackagePath instead of PackFolder everything breaks apart

